# Superhuman: Extreme Temperatures Pt.2

Tags: biology, super-powers, bio-mechanics, temperature, body-modification

I have decided I will add my whole question… I’m new give me a bit of grace…

I am creating a superhuman and I am in need of some helpful tips and answers. 
To get straight to the point I need to know what types of modifications could be made to the human nervous, integumentary, circulatory, and hormonal systems to allow the production of extreme amounts of heat. This extreme amount of temperature is induced through her emotional state.

She can fluctuate her body heat to inhuman levels. Her highest temperature is at 3,000 ℉. She does not stay at this heat at all, this is just her highest possible temperature. She is not immune to overheating but can stay at 3,000 ℉ for only a minute and temperatures higher than 550 ℉ are still a stretch for her.

That’s the first ability, the second is that she secretes three different types of sweat. From her enlarged and retractable exocrine glands, she secretes a potassium nitrate-like sweat. Her sudoriferous glands produce a very sugary and starchy sweat. Finally, the last one is just normal sweat production.

Her skin is made up out of multiple colorless elements. These consist of charcoal, sulfur, aluminum, iron, steel, zinc, and magnesium. They are produced like skin cells are. They only become visible when detonated or moisture is applied and dried.

Finally, she has a multicolored “chalk” substance which is what gives her explosions color. It cannot be detonated but can be set ablaze. The colors are not visible until there is a sudden action. Say someone bumped into her and as a result, a cloud of “chalk” would billow off. The chalk changes colors… also linked to the emotional state but this is completely unrealistic and mostly for making it a showy power.

The gist of this, is I’m making a human firework...

My first idea was to increase the size of the heart and add two more chambers to store and heat blood. Maybe her heart could beat much faster than normal situations. I need to know how much adrenalin and hormones could also be produced. As a cooling system, I was thinking I would implement some sort of hormone much like ones the thyroid produces. I would probably create this hormone. Another thing would have to be modifications to the size of the sweat glands.

I am ignoring certain facts like a human body would incinerate under 3,000 ℉ and that potassium nitrate and the skin elements are impossible for the body to make. Her heart would also explode… and for now, I am ignoring fuel intake because that factor is unrealistic.
I don’t need any modifications for the entire body to sustain such heat, *I need a way for the body to reach said temperature*.

The visibility and realistic qualities of the “chalk” and elements I am also choosing to ignore. I do not need modifications for the human body to produce said elements but if there are any suggestions I am open. Substitutions for the elements and chalk are welcome.

This is a superhuman that has her powers passed down genetically, not given through extraordinary circumstances. Like MetaAbilities, mutants, or quirks.

This is an entirely impossible design but I would still like to implement some scientific reasoning to my design.

```
  Thank you
     - Whimsy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, putting aside the inevitability of a human steak, here we go:

The concept: To heat her up rapidly, she could burn oil stores in her body the transfer energy into her blood. Oil has the benefit of being made from biological materials, and with the advent of biodiesel and specialized bacteria, the oil could conceivably be created within her body in a specialized organ.

The numbers: A liter of crude oil contains 38500KJ. To heat her body up to 3000℉ she would have to store a whopping 21 liters of it(which would weigh approximately 45 pounds). To get up to 550℉, she only needs to store around 3.5 liters.

The act: She could have a combustion chamber somewhere in her chest that has "veins" that are spread through her body and terminate at her pores. These veins would carry air into and out of the chamber and prevent her from exploding from the expansion of the liquid into a gas(at least hopefully it does). Another vein would pump fuel into the chamber.

A final note: The fuel doesn't have to be oil, it's just the easiest I could think of. More efficient fuel like methane and hydrogen would have to have dedicated coolant systems, or else she would pop as the liquids boil inside her.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Incredible! I really like the idea of the combustion chamber. I hadn't even considered that! Using some sort of oil is a brilliant idea. That was my second choice in the early development stages but turned it down because of some other complications in her early design. I have to say oil is definitely the best solution. I will see what others have to say on this matter but so far yours has definitely solved the heating dilemma.

Comment: Humans are great at storing oily energy reserves!  But she would need to keep clothes in lots of different sizes.